# Pentax to Canon EOS

Tags: sigma, lens-adapter, canon-1100d

I have an older Pentax MZ-50 camera that came with a SIGMA 100-300mm lens. Can I get an adaptor so the lens will work with my Canon EOS 1100D?

If so, where can I get one from? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: I suspect the question here contains the link you're looking for: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5692/pentax-to-canon-adapter

Answer (score 2):

[Fotodiox](http://www.fotodioxpro.com/lens-mount-adapters.html) makes a variety of lens mount adapter rings, they have a Pentax K-> Canon EOS one, and I believe it's sold by B&H and Adorama. And there's always eBay.

However, you will want to do some research and find out the effects of adapting a lens like this. You're most likely going to lose the ability to do wide-open metering, shooting in any modes other than M and Av, you won't have lens EXIF, autofocus, or aperture control from the camera body.  And if the Sigma lens has no aperture ring, you'll probably be shooting wide open all the time.

It's not always worth it to try adapting a lens, and the ones that make it the easiest tend to be film-era all-manual lenses.